# Do you have to use IdentityServer 3's login views

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, identityserver3, thinktecture

I'm architecting a SSO service to support multiple internal and client facing applications.  I'm reviewing ThinkTecture's IdentityServer 3 approach using OpenId Connect and oAUTH2.  I think this is the direction we need to go.  However, I'm hung up on the examples I'm seeing where the user is presented a login form served from IdentityServer.  Since I need to develop a SSO service where multiple apps partake, I'd prefer for the individual apps to manage their own login pages.  For example, application A may require Forms Authentication, Facebook, and Google +.  Application B may require only Forms Authentication.  Each app needs to bump against the IdentityServer to return a token.  However, I want the individual apps to manage displaying the login options within their domain.

How do you customize IdentityServer to use client login instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all done by configuring the clients. Every client has a `EnableLocalLogin` option which control forms based authentication. Also every client an `IdentityProviderRestrictions` list that controls which external IdPs are available.

check the docs:
https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/clients.html